# Why has Jupyter notebook kernel stopped working after RStudio package installation

Tags: jupyter

To date I have been using Jupyter Notebook to run R and sometimes Python code. I have also been using RStudio at times. Recently, while using RStudio, I was prompted to install some package (cannot exactly remember). At any rate, I installed this package. Dont know if only coincidence, but trying to run R in the notebook resulted in kernel not connecting. I found the same issue with Python, the Python kernel is also not connecting anymore.

Executing the below, I get;
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
ir         C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir
python3    C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3

How do I get Jupyter Notebook's kernels to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Executing IRkernel::installspec() in R via Anaconda CMD prompt have resolved the issue. Note for others with this issue, you may be prompted to run install.packages(“rlang”) before.